# How to do a nested javascript library promise callback inside angular rxjs subscribe call

Tags: javascript, angular, html2canvas, angular9, zone

I have a requirement whenever an error occurred I need to collect basic error trace,IP address, and screenshot.

For the Ip address, I am using this API to get IP address. getIp:'http://api.ipify.org/?format=json'.
For ScreenShot using Html2 Canvas:library:https://github.com/niklasvh/html2canvas/issues/2282.

This is the method triggers when error occurs.

I have added await but it is not waiting for the response from callback it will return before callback execution happens.

initially call

```
getIP(response:any)
  {
// call 1
    this.getIPAddress().subscribe(async(res:any)=>{ 
    this.ipAddress = res.ip;  
// get an ip once ip recieved call another function


    let errorRequest =  await this.logError(response); call 2
// another service call
    this.logErrorRequest(errorRequest); //  send another service call to server to store the error
    });

    return  errorDetails;
  }
```

the second call .. in this method format the request. Here for screenshot, i  need to call javascript library html2canvas. await this.getScreenShot()

// problem here is the method will return a response before getting a response from that promise call.

```
async logError(response:any):ErrorRequest{
    error={
        ExceptionMessage:response.message,
        ipAddress:this.ipAddress,
        screenShot:await this.getScreenShot()    // next call 3.
    };
   
    return error;
}
```

// promise call back

```
async getScreenShot() {
    this.zone.runOutsideAngular(() => {
// call 4
      html2canvas(document.querySelector("#capture")).then(canvas => {
      canvas.toBlob(function(blob){
                let link = document.createElement("a");
                link.download = "image.png";
                link.href = URL.createObjectURL(blob);
                link.click();
                let screenShot = blob; 
                 this.screenShot = blob;

            },'image/png');

   
         //your code
      })   

    });
```

Answer (score 0):

You are not returning anything from your `getScreenShot()`, except `Promise<void>` but that's just because of the `async`. It also feels like the first 2 calls do not depend on each other, so you can do them in parallel:

This means, to just fix your issue, you need to refactor your `getScreenShot()` method:

```
getScreenShot() {
  return this.zone.runOutsideAngular(async () => {
    const canvas = await html2canvas(document.getElementById("capture"));

    return new Promise(
      (resolve) => canvas.toBlob((blob) => resolve(blob), 'image/png')
    );
  });
}
```

In short, return the `this.zone` call, await the `html2canvas` call, create a new promise and return this in your resolve. Also, don't use the `function` keyword, because that's going to mess up the `this` context.

---

The longer fix which would require a refactoring of your code would look something like this:

```
logError(response: { message: string }): void {
  forkJoin([
    this.getIPAddress(),
    this.getScreenShot()
  ]).pipe(
    concatMap(([ { ip }, screenshot ]) => this.logErrorRequest({
      ExceptionMessage: response.message,
      ipAddress: ip,
      screenshot
    }))
  ).subscribe({
    next: () => console.log('error logged'),
    error: () => console.log('make sure to catch this to prevent loop!')
  });
}
```

This will obviously use the refactored `getScreenShot` method. As you might see, this is a lot more clear, and evades the use of random `this` assignments. It's a nice stream, just like rxjs wants things.

<sub>Also make sure that you somehow debounce/group the logging of errors, to prevent a flooding or infinite loop of errors being logged. Trust me, it happens :D</sub>

Comment: krujit nice .. let me try this and will update you.. thanks for your valuable comments